# How is Period, Comma, Semi colon, Colon read?

Tags: punctuation, reading

I understand that, when encountering a period, comma, semi-colon, or a comma, in reading something aloud, one normally makes a slight pause. Does the length of that pause depend on which of these punctuation marks it corresponds to? For example, do people, on average, pause for longer when encountering a period, than when encountering a comma?

Comment: I'm not convinced this can be answered definitively (everyone is different), although there are certain customary intonations like the rise at the end of a question. The best thing to do is to listen to examples. But there is too much asked about here anyway.

Comment: @AndrewLeach how much more focused should it be? should I ask 14 questions for all of   them?

Comment: No. If you do that they will all be closed as opinion based (everyone is different), probably downvoted, and you will end up question-banned. If you must ask, choose **one** and ask it on [ELL.SE]

Comment: @AndrewLeach so there isn't any rule that says these punctuations should be read in this way? why are they opinion based?

Comment: It's opinion based because everyone does it differently. Apart from question intonation; that's more-or-less universal. But your question indicates you should be asking on our sister site. How ELL regulate questions may be different to ELU, but it's still recommended to restrict the scope of questions asked.

Comment: The information you have read is incorrect. Punctuation marks do not indicate pauses, and pauses are not measured in seconds. Punctuation marks sometimes indicate sounds, but often they don't indicate anything at all, like the apostrophe.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, there may be a good reason for asking these questions together, because, even if none of them can be answered in absolute terms (such as '1.3 seconds), it is not unreasonable to wonder whether they might be answerable in relative terms. For example, is the pause corresponding to a semi-colon, typically, on average, longer than the pause corresponding to a comma? If it turns out that they are, on average, of the same length, that would be an answer, rather than a reason for dismissing the question. That is an interesting question and well out of the ELL domain.

Comment: @jsw If you'd like to edit the question, please do.

Comment: @jsw29: Once again, There are no pauses associated with any punctuation mark. That's a fiction, like the space character between words, which doesn't indicate anything in speech, either. If there are no pauses, they cannot be measured. If they cannot be measured, they cannot be compared. Which is lucky, since they don't exist, and anybody comparing them would be foolish, like measuring ghosts.

Comment: @JohnLawler, the OP did not make up the claim that some punctuation marks correspond to pauses in speech; it appears in numerous sources. If it is your expert opinion that this is a fiction, you could help very many people by dispelling that fiction in an answer. Your comments thus provide a strong reason for reopening the question.

Comment: [I've been trying to do that for years](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+comma+pause). Once every 3 years, apparently. Guess it's time for another, though maybe not for a closed question.